# Sufficient and necessary condition for strictly monotone differentiable functions

Tags: calculus, analysis

I read from a book without proof the following theorem: Let $f(x)$ be a differentiable function, then $f(x)$ is strictly increasing if and only if $f'(x) \geq 0$, and $f'(x) \gt 0$ almost everywhere. Is it correct? I doubt, but I could neither prove it nor give a counter example.

Comment: Monotonic should be replaced by increasing.

Comment: Do you agree that $f$ is increasing iff its derivative is non negative? Is it the "almost everywhere positive" part that is posing a problem? The first part has one obvious direction : if you are increasing then the derivative must be everywhere non negative. The other direction (non negative derivative implies increasing) follows from Rolle : if $a<b$ then there exists $a<c<b$ with $f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)\geq 0$.

Comment: yes, the problem is the "almost everywhere positive" part.

Comment: One direction is not too hard : if $f'$ is $\geq 0$ almost everywhere $>0$ then $f$ must be stricly increasing. For take $a<b$. Since $f'\geq 0$, by what precedes you have $f$ increasing. On the other hand, since $f'>0$ almost everywhere, you can find $a<c<b$ with $f'(c)>0$ and by definition of $f'(c)$ as a limit you can find $c<d<b$ close to $c$ with $$\frac{f(d)-f(c)}{d-c}>\frac{1}{2}f'(c)>0.$$ Thus $$f(a)\leq f(c)<f(d)\leq f(b)$$ which shows that $f$ is stricly increasing. The two $\leq$ come from $f$ being increasing, while the $<$ comes from the difinition of $c$ and $d$.

Comment: So actually it's a sufficient additional condition that $f'(x)>0$ on a dense set. This is also necessary, due to the mean value theorem.

Comment: @Henning Makholm True. So the actual theorem should read for $f$ differentiable *f stricly increasing iff $f'\geq 0$ and $f'>0$ on a dense set.*.

Comment: @Olivier, I'm not convinced that the "almost everywhere" version cannot also be true. Perhaps "$f'>0$ on a dense set" implies "$f'>0$ almost everywhere". If only $f$ were $C^1$ we could probably argue this by continutity, but that isn't necessarily the case. _Or is it?_

Comment: The same question is being asked on mathoverflow.

Comment: @Henning Makholm I'm wondering the same thing!

Comment: @AliBleybel care to share a link to said MO question?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/79671/sufficient-and-necessary-condition-for-strictly-monotone-differentiable-functions

Comment: I'll quote my comment from mathoverflow here also, which gives a counterexample to the statement in the question. "...look at the integral of a continuous function vanishing on the fat cantor set $C$. Eg, $f(x)=\int g(x)\,dx$ with $g(x)$ being the distance from $x$ to $C$ will do. Then $f^\prime=0$ on $C$, which has positive measure, but $f$ is continuously differentiable and strictly increasing."

Comment: How can $f'=0$ on $C$ which is dense (I suppose) and still $f'\neq 0$ everywhere? Or maybe I am saying nonsense?

Comment: $C$ is not dense. See my answer (and I linked to the Wikipedia page describing $C$).

Comment: @Olivier: If $f^\prime=0$ almost everywhere and the derivative of $f$ exists everywhere, then $f$ must be constant. It need not be constant if you don't also require the everywhere differentiability of $f$.

Comment: @Henning Makholm: No, my counterexample shows that is false even for $f\in C^1$ (you can even improve my counterexample to be $C^\infty$).

Comment: @George Lowther How do you see this? (the fact that $f'=0$ almost everywhere and $f$ everywhere differentiable implies $f$ constant) Also what happens when you only ask for $f'=0$ on a dense set?

Comment: @Olivier: Using a bit of measure theory you can write $f(b)-f(a)=\int_a^bf^\prime(x)\,dx$ if $f$ is increasing and everywhere differentiable.

Comment: So $f$ would be absolutely continuous? I really don't know much about this stuff ^^

Comment: @Olivier: Yes. Everywhere differentiable increasing functions are absolutely continuous. I couldn't give a reference, it's just something I worked out. But if you understand the proof of Lebesgue's theorems concerning differentiability of finite variation functions, it's not too hard to generalize from there.

Comment: @George Lowther I will give it a shot tomorow morning!

Comment: @Olivier: Just requiring $f^\prime=0$ on a dense set...hmm. With the other conditions, I think that will imply that it is constant, but I can't quite see it yet...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1692/discussion-between-george-lowther-and-olivier-begassat)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A necessary and sufficient condition is that $f^\prime\ge0$ everywhere and $f^\prime > 0$ on a *dense* subset of $\mathbb{R}$. The condition stated in the question is sufficient, but not necessary. Consider the following differentiable and strictly increasing function for which $f^\prime > 0$ does not hold almost everywhere. Let $C$ be the [fat Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) (which is closed with positive measure, but does not contain any nontrivial open intervals). Let $g(x)$ be the distance from any point $x$ to $C$. Then, $g$ is continuous and vanishes precisely on $C$. The integral
$$
f(x)=\int_0^xg(y)\,dy
$$
is strictly increasing and continuously differentiable, but $f^\prime=0$ on $C$.

We can show that $f^\prime\ge0$ everywhere and $f^\prime > 0$ on a dense set is indeed necessary and sufficient for $f$ to be strictly increasing (see also  Olivier Bégassat's comments to the question).

**Sufficiency**: If $f^\prime\ge0$ then the mean value theorem implies that $f$ is increasing. If it was not strictly increasing then we would have $f(a)=f(b)$ for some $a < b$ implying that $f^\prime=0$ on $[a,b]$, contradicting the condition that $f^\prime > 0$ on a dense set. This proves sufficiency of the conditions.

**Necessity**: In the other direction, suppose that $f$ is strictly increasing. Then, $f^\prime\ge0$ follows directly from the definition of the derivative. Also, $f(a) < f(b)$ for any $a < b$. The mean value theorem implies that $f^\prime(x) > 0$ for some $x\in[a,b]$. So, $f^\prime > 0$ on a dense set.

Comment: Your example shows that $f$ stricly increasing need not imply that $f'$ be positve almost everywhere. I was wondering wether $f'=0$ on a dense set implies $f$ constant. All being the same of course : $f$ is still increasing and differentiable everywhere.

Comment: @George: Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the proposed "almost everywhere" criterion is not correct: it is sufficient, but not necessary, for $f$ to be strictly increasing.

In his very nice answer, George Lowther has given a correct necessary and sufficient condition: namely that $f'(x) > 0$ on a dense subset of the domain.  As it happens, I recently covered this topic in my "Spivak calculus class" and found that even Spivak's text didn't give quite the treatment of this point that I wanted.  So I wrote something up myself.  Here is the statement:

[Warning: where others here say "strictly increasing", I say "increasing"; where others say "increasing", I say "weakly increasing", and similarly for "monotone" and "weakly monotone".]

---

**Second Monotone Function Theorem**:
Let $f: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function which is continuous on $I$ and differentiable on the interior $I^{\circ}$ of $I$.
a) The following are equivalent:
(i) $f$ is weakly monotone.
(ii) Either we have $f'(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in I^{\circ}$ or $f'(x) \leq 0$
for all $x \in I^{\circ}$.
b) Suppose $f$ is weakly monotone.  The following are equivalent:
(i) $f$ is *not* monotone.
(ii) There exist $a,b \in I^{\circ}$ with $a < b$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $[a,b]$ is constant.
(iii) There exist $a,b \in I^{\circ}$ with $a < b$ such that $f'(x) = 0$ for all
$x \in [a,b]$.

---

Note that my statement of the equivalence is slightly different (and, perhaps, slightly simpler?) than George's.  For the proof, please see $\S 5.1$ of [these notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/2400calc2.pdf).  Finally, note that when George appeals to the Intermediate Value Theorem I think he really means to appeal (as I do) to the Mean Value Theorem, although (confusingly, for students) these names are not completely standardized even among mathematicians.

Comment: I did intend to use the mean value theorem. I corrected my answer, thanks!